# How to get data from JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I want to print data one by one using JSON array.

```
[
{
"meta_device_id":"NEA8000000345",
"name":"Jaffna",
"description":"aq",
"latitude":9.779333,
"longitude":80.04059,
"pm10":31.0,
"pm25":55.0,
"pm100":74.0,
"co2":4996.0,
"temperature":27.94,
"timestamp":1647383654251
}, 

{
"meta_device_id":"NEA8000011",
"name":"Galle",
"description":"MET Department, Galle",
"latitude":6.0297956,
"longitude":80.21212,
"pm10":28.0,
"pm25":43.0,
"pm100":52.0,
"co2":2264.81,
"temperature":34.59,
"timestamp":1647398582681
}
]
```

This is my json array. I want to take meta_device_id for variable . How can I do it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract and access data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-to-extract-and-access-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: @AndreaOlivato Thanks for the replay. I check this example also but always show empty. '$json = file_get_contents('http://123.231.44.147/nbro-invoker/api/sensor/flat-info');
$yummy = json_decode($json);
echo $yummy->meta_device_id;  This is the code I use.

Comment: That's because the API returns an array of json objects, so trying to access the meta_device_id property will not work. You'd have to specify which device you want to access either by using the index, e.g. `$yummy[0]->meta_device_id`. Or, you could use `array_column` to grab an array of device ids for all devices returned from the API call, like this demo https://3v4l.org/ovAZa. Or do `foreach($yummy as $yum)` to gain access to each JSON object in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to `decode` your result `json` and then either loop through your data to get `meta_device_id` or you can get value by `array index.`

```
$string = '[
{
"meta_device_id":"NEA8000000345",
"name":"Jaffna",
"description":"aq",
"latitude":9.779333,
"longitude":80.04059,
"pm10":31.0,
"pm25":55.0,
"pm100":74.0,
"co2":4996.0,
"temperature":27.94,
"timestamp":1647383654251
}, 

{
"meta_device_id":"NEA8000011",
"name":"Galle",
"description":"MET Department, Galle",
"latitude":6.0297956,
"longitude":80.21212,
"pm10":28.0,
"pm25":43.0,
"pm100":52.0,
"co2":2264.81,
"temperature":34.59,
"timestamp":1647398582681
}
]';

 $yummy = json_decode($string);
```

Now you can loop through your data and store values in an array.

```
 $myarr = array();
 $i=0;
 foreach($yummy as $yum)
 {
  $myarr[$i] = $yum->meta_device_id;
  $i++;
 }
 var_dump($myarr); // array(2) { [0]=> string(13) "NEA8000000345" [1]=> string(10) "NEA8000011" }
```

OR you can get values by index.

```
var_dump($yummy[0]->meta_device_id); // NEA8000000345
var_dump($yummy[0]->meta_device_id); // NEA8000011
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Yep this code is work thanks again. I have one more question. for $string how can use API url. I checked using below code but it's not working. '$string1 = 'http://123.231.44.147/nbro-invoker/api/sensor/flat-info';
$string = file_get_contents($string1);
 $yummy = json_decode($string);
 $myarr = array();
 $i=0;
 foreach($yummy as $yum)
 {
  $myarr[$i] = $yum->meta_device_id;
  $i++;
 }
 var_dump($myarr); // array(2) { [0]=> string(13) "NEA8000000345" [1]=> string(10) "NEA8000011" } '

Comment: you can curl your api and pass result into $string.